# Как в Unity открыть окно оценки игры в Google Play?

Tags: unity3d

Я знаю про способ перехода на страницу приложения в Google Play с помощью Application.OpenURL.
Но в некоторых играх я видел, как прямо во время игры снизу открывается аккуратненькая панелька гугл плея с быстрой оценкой игры. Как такое сделать в Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй использовать код ниже. Но для начала не забудь установить плагин: https://developers.google.com/unity/packages#play_in-app_review

Да, и учти квоты на вызов этого окна: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review#quotas

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Google.Play.Review;

private IEnumerator RatePopupForGooglePlay()
{
    ReviewManager _reviewManager = new ReviewManager();
    var requestFlowOperation = _reviewManager.RequestReviewFlow();
    yield return requestFlowOperation;

    if (requestFlowOperation.Error != ReviewErrorCode.NoError)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    PlayReviewInfo _playReviewInfo = requestFlowOperation.GetResult();

    var launchFlowOperation = _reviewManager.LaunchReviewFlow(_playReviewInfo);
    yield return launchFlowOperation;

    if (launchFlowOperation.Error != ReviewErrorCode.NoError)
    {
        yield break;
    }
}
```